# How to query child processes in C++

Tags: c++, linux, fork, execv

My c++ program will spawn several child processes using fork() and execv(). How can I query those processes? If I wanted to shut one down, how would I do that?

Answer (score 5):

When you `fork`, the return value is 0 in the child process, and the child's process ID (pid) in the parent process.

You can then call `kill` with that pid to see if it's still running, or request a shutdown. To check if the process is running, use 0 as the signal, then check the return value (0 == running; -1 == not running). To request a shutdown, use `SIGTERM` as the signal.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way that I know of to communicate between processes after a `fork()` is through sockets (see [socketpair()](http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/netguide/dusockD.socketpairs_codetext.html)).

From there, you can probably make anything work by just defining a protocol for communication (including the request to terminate).

Answer (score 0):

After a call to `fork()`, you can use either `wait(&status_int)` or `waitpid(child_pid, &status_int, WNOHANG)` to detect the return status of children, using the latter if you don't want to block waiting for a child.  The passed argument `&status_int` would be a pointer to an `int` that will hold the return status of the child process after it has exited.  If you want to wait for any forked process to complete, and don't care about the return value, you can simply make a call to `wait(NULL)`, or for a non-blocking version, `waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG)`.